# Issue reaching gmail from google cloud run container

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm facing some difficulty sending mails (using JavaMail) from within Google Cloud Run container. I get java.net.SocketTimeoutException. It's not clear to me if this is due to a firewall/network restriction with cloud run. Are cloud run containers restricted from accessing the internet?

Comment: What port are you connecting to. Port 25 is blocked. More details are required on exactly what configuration you have setup to connect to Gmail (SMTP, IMAP, etc), port numbers, authentication, etc.

Comment: Thanks John, I tried both TLS - 587 and SSL - 465, pointing to the smpt server for gmail - 
`spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com

spring.mail.port=465 

spring.mail.ssl.enable=true 
spring.mail.auth=true`

Comment: You are not providing enough details. Cloud Run is not blocking 465 or 587. I would test the container locally and once working correctly then in Cloud Run. Verify that you can connect to Gmail using this command: `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`. If you receive the Gmail banner, type `quit`. Otherwise you have a network problem. Note: port 465 and 587 are different. One uses TLS by default and the other uses STARTTLS. Review your code to set up the correct configuration.

Comment: Same problem. I still can send email last week but now can't. Can't understand why too much error with Google Cloud Platform. Supporting service is terrible. I think Azure is more better. https://twitter.com/TranNgocKhoa/status/1328388861727182848